# form_with search field in Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

In Rails 5.1 all the forms have to be done with `form_with`. In http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/5_1_release_notes.html#unification-of-form-for-and-form-tag-into-form-with I can only find examples for forms which are related to models.

What is the correct way for this Rails 5.0 form to be done in Rails 5.1 with `form_with`?

```
<%= form_tag("/search", method: "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is `form_with` call, that is exact equivalent to the `form_tag` call from the question:

```
<%= form_with url: '/search', method: :get, local: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :q, "Search for:" %>
  <%= f.text_field :q, id: :q %>
  <%= f.submit "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

Note that `form_with` is sent via XHR (a.k.a `remote: true`) by default, and you have to add `local: true` to make it behave like `form_tag`'s default `remote: false`.

See more about it in [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-with), [API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with) and [this github issue discussion](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25197).

Answer (score 6):

`form_with` is updated feature in  `rails 5.1` and its unified way to create form in rails it can be used as `form_for` or `form_with` its contain certain options

> **:url** - The URL the form submits to. Akin to values passed to url_for or link_to. For example, you may use a named route directly. When a :scope is passed without a :url the form just submits to the current URL.
>
> **:method** - The method to use when submitting the form, usually either “get” or “post”. If “patch”, “put”, “delete”, or another verb is used, a hidden input named _method is added to simulate the verb over post.
>
> **:format** - The format of the route the form submits to. Useful when submitting to another resource type, like :json. Skipped if a :url is passed.
>
> **:scope** - The scope to prefix input field names with and thereby how the submitted parameters are grouped in controllers.
>
> **:model** - A model object to infer the :url and :scope by, plus fill out input field values. So if a title attribute is set to “Ahoy!” then a title input field's value would be “Ahoy!”. If the model is a new record a create form is generated, if an existing record, however, an update form is generated. Pass :scope or :url to override the defaults. E.g. turn params[:post] into params[:article].
>
> **:authenticity_token** - Authenticity token to use in the form. Override with a custom authenticity token or pass false to skip the authenticity token field altogether. Useful when submitting to an external resource like a payment gateway that might limit the valid fields. Remote forms may omit the embedded authenticity token by setting config.action_view.embed_authenticity_token_in_remote_forms = false. This is helpful when fragment-caching the form. Remote forms get the authenticity token from the meta tag, so embedding is unnecessary unless you support browsers without JavaScript.
>
> **:local** - By default form submits are remote and unobstrusive XHRs.
>   Disable remote submits with local: true.
>
> **:skip_enforcing_utf8** - By default a hidden field named utf8 is output
>   to enforce UTF-8 submits. Set to true to skip the field.
>
> **:builder** - Override the object used to build the form.
>
> **:id** - Optional HTML id attribute.
>
> **:class** - Optional HTML class attribute.
>
> **:data** - Optional HTML data attributes.
>
> **:html** - Other optional HTML attributes for the form tag.

### Example

```
<%= form_with(model: @post, url: super_posts_path) %>
<%= form_with(model: @post, scope: :article) %>
<%= form_with(model: @post, format: :json) %>
<%= form_with(model: @post, authenticity_token: false) %>
```

### Example of namespaced routes of `form_with`

For namespaced routes, like admin_post_url:

```
<%= form_with(model: [ :admin, @post ]) do |form| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

with associated resource

If your resource has associations defined, for example, you want to add comments to the document given that the routes are set correctly:

```
<%= form_with(model: [ @document, Comment.new ]) do |form| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

for more info checkout [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with)

Answer (score 1):

You may use `form_with` like this:

```
<%= form_with(url: '/search') do |f| %>
  <%= f.label(:q, "Search for:") %>
  <%= f.text_field(:q, id: :q) %>
  <%= f.submit("Search") %>
<% end %>
```