# Intermittent ActionController::UnknownFormat error in remote form with Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller

I have a `form_with` that submits remotely and works perfectly for almost everyone. However, every once in a while, a user gets this error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat: TestimonialsController#create is missing a template for this request format and variant.

request.formats: ["text/html"]
request.variant: []
```

*View:*

```
<%= form_with(model: [@event, @testimonial]) do |form| %>
...
<% end %>
```

*Action:*

```
def create
  @testimonial = @event.testimonials.find_or_initialize_by(user: Current.user)
  @testimonial.assign_attributes testimonial_params.merge({status: :pending})
  @testimonial.save
end
```

*Response:*

It's in a file called `create.js.erb`

**Question:** I have looked everywhere but I have not idea why certain users request HTML instead of JS, which is what every other user gets. What am I missing? I really don't want to support HTML responses.

Comment: You mean you want to answer every requests as if it was a `JSON` request?

Comment: Not quite. `form_with` submits all requests using XHR and expects a JS response.  But a small part of the requests seem to be submitting through standard HTML and therefore expecint HTML responses. I want to understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your server may be receiving requests in different formats and trying to serve them accordingly:

- `GET www.my_server.com/resource.html`
- `GET www.my_server.com/resource.json`
- Or a strange format `GET www.my_server.com/resource.what`

This is the desired behavior in Rails. Take a look into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4800375/8304905) about how to change the default format for your routes, or you may change them all to be of type `json` in your `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_default_response_format

  protected

  def set_default_response_format
    request.format = :json
  end
end
```

The important line is `request.format = :json`, which can be used in only one controller or just one of its actions.

If you want your code to always respond in `json`, then you may want to take a look into [Using Rails for API-only Applications](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html)

Comment: Yes, I'm receiving requests for different formats and that's what I don't understand. `form_with` defaults to XHR requests and expects JS responses. And it works. But a small subset of users, somehow, are submitting the form through standard HTML and expecting HTML as a response. I want to understand why that happens and how to prevent it.

Comment: Try `form_with(model: [@event, @testimonial], format: :json)`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45071735/8304905) may help you.